# Google Translator in Android

Tags: android, google-translate

I code abide by http://android-er.blogspot.com/2009/10/multi-language-translate.html

and it force close

```
private void showLang() {
    db.open();
    cursor = db.getLang();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    SimpleCursorAdapter qc = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            cursor,
            new String[] {DBAdapter.KEY_LANG},
            new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
        qc.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        Language_Spinner.setAdapter(qc);

        TranslateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                String InputString;
                String OutputString = null;
                InputString = Thai_word.getText().toString();

                String language = (String)Language_Spinner
                .getItemAtPosition((int) Language_Spinner.getSelectedItemId());

                try {
                    Translate.setHttpReferrer("http://android-er.blogspot.com/");
                    OutputString = Translate.execute(InputString,
                            Language.ENGLISH,Language.THAI);

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    OutputString = "Error";
              }
                Target_word.setText(OutputString+language);
            }       
        });

}
```

}

this is my logcat

> 02-12 21:45:44.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(437): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   02-12 21:45:44.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(437): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor
>   02-12 21:45:44.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(437):     at com.android.proj.Sens_Create$1.onClick(Sens_Create.java:133)
>   02-12 21:45:44.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(437):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
>   02-12 21:45:44.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(437):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
>   02-12 21:45:44.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(437):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>   02-12 21:45:44.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(437):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   02-12 21:45:44.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(437):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   02-12 21:45:44.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(437):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   02-12 21:45:44.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(437):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   02-12 21:45:44.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(437):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   02-12 21:45:44.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(437):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   02-12 21:45:44.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(437):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>   02-12 21:45:44.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(437):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

please help

Comment: what does this have to do with google app engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String language = (String)Language_Spinner
                .getItemAtPosition((int) Language_Spinner.getSelectedItemId());
```

I think your problem is here.  This method does not return a string, thus the class cast exception occurs.

Comment: @user432209 sorry for bother again, I want to use String from spinner cause in my database I use Thai language and if I pass Thai language to Google tran (as input language to tran)it won't work so I have to get Thai String from database and change it to English String (So that is way I try to use (String)Language_Spinner...) do you have any idea? please help